# Ошибка о неявном преобразовании

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Есть такой код:

```
class Presenter
{
    public  List<Objects> GetObjects()
    {
        var context = new LocalDBEntities();

        var objects = from c in context.Objects
                      join t in context.Types on c.TypeID equals t.TypeID
                      join s in context.Status on c.StatusID equals s.StatusID
                      select new
                      {
                          c.NameObject,
                          s.NameStatus,
                          t.NameType
                      };

        objects.ToList();
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Здесь использую:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Presenter presenter = new Presenter();
    var objects = presenter.GetObjects();


    int count = 0;
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(obj.NameObject);
        treeView1.Nodes[count].Nodes.Add(obj.NameType);
        treeView1.Nodes[count].Nodes.Add(obj.NameStatus);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Класс Objects

```
public partial class Objects
{
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string NameObject { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Types Types { get; set; }
}
```

Метод GetObjects() возвращает список объектов, но так как выбраны три объекта в запросе, то выдает ошибку о неявном преобразовании. Что можно исправить/сделать в методе GetObjects() класса Presentrer, чтобы в обработчике Form1_Load ничего не менять?

Comment: Вы создаете коллекцию анонимных объектов, а не объектов типа `Objects`. Почему бы не переписать так: `... select c;`?

Comment: А вообще, конечно, все эти `join` в EF не нужны, пользуйтесь навигационными свойствами. Такое ощущение, что вы пишете сначала SQL, а потом дословно переводите его в linq, так не надо делать, надо мыслить сразу в терминах ООП

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не помогло, теперь такая ошибка: "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Linq.IQueryable<test.Objects>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<test.Objects>". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)." Теперь такая ошибка

Comment: @Bald не помогает "Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Linq.IQueryable<test.Objects>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<test.Objects>". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов)."

Comment: `return objects.ToList();` А эту строчку выкиньте `objects.ToList();` - она бессмысленна, т.к. вы не сохраняете результат.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Теперь не могу указать NameType и NameStatus объекта в обработчике Form1_Load()

Comment: @Bald Добавил класс Objects к вопросу

Comment: @Bald `context.Objects.Include(x=>x.Types).Include(x=>x.Status).Select(x=> new Objects{}).ToList();` выдает ошибку: Не удается преобразовать лямбда-выражение к типу "string", так как он не является типом делегата

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80268/discussion-between-bald-and-lets-drum).

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за помощь.
Готовый вариант.
Обработчик:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Presenter presenter = new Presenter();
    var objects = presenter.GetObjects();            

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(obj.NameObject);
        treeView1.Nodes[count].Nodes.Add(obj.Types.NameType);
        treeView1.Nodes[count].Nodes.Add(obj.Status.NameStatus);
        count++;
    }
}
```

Класс Presenter:

```
public List<Objects> GetObjects()
{
    var context = new LocalDBEntities();

    var objects = context.Objects.Include(x => x.Types).Include(x => x.Status).ToList();

    return objects;
}
```